# How can I get Karma + Webpack to find the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner, webpack

I want to run my tests on a bunch of modules after webpack has combined them together through the Karma test runner, but whenever I run my tests Karma says,

> "Error: Cannot find module "hello.js" at
>   http://localhost:9877/base/src/hello.spec.js?d301966ffc1330826574d9d8fff5a644c3390c68:47"

I have a spec file:

```
var a = require('hello.js');

describe("a test test", function() {

  it("humperdink test", function() {
    expect(a).toEqual('humperdink');
  }); //end it

}); //end describe
```

hello.js is this:

```
var a = 'humperdink';

module.exports = a;
```

Both of these files are in the same folder.

My karma.conf.js is:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'tests/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'tests/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
      'src/**/*.js' : ['webpack']
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    webpack: {
      entry: './src/hello.spec.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  })
};
```

Currently my devDependencies installed are

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-jshint-preprocessor": "0.0.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.19",
    "sinon": "^1.17.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
```

How do I get Karma to find the hello.js module?

I've tried changing the spec file's first line to things like

```
require('hello.js');
```

or

```
require('./hello.js');
```

or

```
require('hello');
```

on the advice of [Karma Webpack - Error: Cannot find module "./test/utilities.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152927/karma-webpack-error-cannot-find-module-test-utilities-js)

I don't think there's anything too complicated going on here like, [Cannot find module error when using karma-webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860762/cannot-find-module-error-when-using-karma-webpack).

I have checked to make sure that the Karma test runner is working otherwise. If I run a really simple test in its own file it works just fine.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try `require('../src/hello');`?

Comment: I did, before I moved both files to the same directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have replicate your project and fix it. Following the https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack

In the spec:

```
var a = require('../src/hello.js');
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      //'src/**/*.js', <-------- Remove or comment this
      'tests/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'tests/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
      'src/**/*.js' : ['webpack']
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    webpack: {
      entry: './tests/hello.spec.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  })
};
```

[image: karma specs result in terminal]

And additionally for **npm test** command:
in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start"
}
```